# which rounding rounding datetime is more efficient in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm going to write a code that round a datetime value but i can't compare which ones is more efficient:

```
DECLARE @DateValue DATETIME = '2021-01-13 11:59:59'

---- FIRST SOLUSTION:
SELECT CAST(@DateValue AS smalldatetime) AS DateRoundS1


---- SECOND SOLUTION:
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, @DateValue) AS DateRoundS2

---- THIRD SOLUTION:
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, @DateValue), 0) AS DateRoundS3

---- FORTH SOLUTION:
DECLARE @DateValue DATETIME = '2021-01-13 11:59:59'
DECLARE @DiffMinsTime INT = DATEPART(MINUTE,@DateValue)
DECLARE @DiffSecsTime INT = DATEPART(SECOND,@DateValue)
DECLARE @DiffMSTime INT = DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@DateValue)

IF( @DiffMinsTime > 0 )
BEGIN
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@DiffMinsTime,@DateValue),0)
END
    IF(@DiffSecsTime > 0)
    BEGIN
       SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,@DiffSecsTime,@DateValue),0)
    END
       IF(@DiffMSTime > 0)
       BEGIN
            SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@DiffMSTime,@DateValue),0)
       END
```

PS: I know the last one has overflow!!
Is there any more efficient way to do that?!

Comment: What means 'efficient'? Are trying to convert millions of rows? Tell us some context!

Comment: But `CAST` and `CONVERT` are very fast, but so are many of the date and time functions (like `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`). What are you trying to "round" the time to here?

Comment: Tip1 - use DATETIME2

Comment: 1 & 2 are  exactly the same, `CAST` just calls `CONVERT`. 3 will be pretty fast also. 4 looks slow. I normally do `CAST(@DateValue AS date)`

Comment: Why would you consider using anything *other* than `cast()`/`convert()`?

Answer (score 0):

With conversions and transformations it always depends on lots of factors.
Best way: Build a test rig and set aside a few minutes or better hours.

The test rig creates numbers from 0 to 9 999 999 - about 10 million rows. Kudos to Jeff Moden for the SQL spackle that creates the number list.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #numbers
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dates
;
CREATE TABLE 
  #numbers
(
  number     integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE
  #dates
(
  dated      datetime2(7) NOT NULL
)
;
WITH
  cteNum
(
  smallnum
)
AS
(
  SELECT Cast( 1 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 2 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 3 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 4 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 5 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 6 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 7 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 8 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 9 AS integer )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 0 AS integer )
)
INSERT INTO 
  #numbers
(
  number
)
SELECT 
  num1.smallnum * 1000000 + num2.smallnum * 100000 + num3.smallnum * 10000 + num4.smallnum * 1000
  + num5.smallnum * 100 + num6.smallnum * 10 + num7.smallnum
FROM
  cteNum AS num1
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num2
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num3
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num4
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num5
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num6
  CROSS JOIN cteNum AS num7
;
INSERT INTO
  #dates
(
  dated
)
SELECT 
  Cast( DateAdd( ms, nums.number, dated.basedate) AS datetime2(7) ) AS dated
FROM 
  #numbers AS nums
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT Cast(GetDate() AS datetime2(7) ) AS basedate
  ) dated
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #numbers
;
```

This will take from a couple of seconds to a couple of minutes to create.
Using a table minimises the amount of effort to table maintenance done by the query analyzer.

The test of conversion times can then be done in a controlled environment. Tip: Using a start and end time capture eliminates the overhead for a SQL trace.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
;
DECLARE 
  @datetimestarted    datetime2(7),
  @datetimeended      datetime2(7),
  @result             varchar(200),
  @crlf               char(2) = char(13) + char(10)
;
SET @datetimestarted = Getdate()
;
SELECT
  dated,
  datedrounded = Cast( dated AS datetime2(0) )
FROM
  #dates
;
SET @datetimeended = Getdate()
;
SET @result = 'Processing time = ' + Cast( Datediff( ms, @datetimestarted, @datetimeended ) / 1000 AS varchar(12) ) + ' seconds' + @crlf
  + ' > Start time: ' + Convert( varchar(20), @datetimestarted, 126 ) + @crlf
  + ' > End time: ' + Convert( varchar(20), @datetimeended, 126 ) + @crlf
;
PRINT @result
;
SET @datetimestarted = Getdate()
;
SELECT
  dated,
  datedrounded = Convert( datetime2(0), dated )
FROM
  #dates
;
SET @datetimeended = Getdate()
;
SET @result = 'Processing time = ' + Cast( Datediff( ms, @datetimestarted, @datetimeended ) / 1000 AS varchar(12) ) + ' seconds' + @crlf
  + ' > Start time: ' + Convert( varchar(20), @datetimestarted, 126 ) + @crlf
  + ' > End time: ' + Convert( varchar(20), @datetimeended, 126 ) + @crlf
;
PRINT @result
;
```

Run time on my VM is about 3 minutes for each option with Cast taking a tad bit longer than Convert. Now this depends on what one wants to achieve so feel free to change the transformations as required.

And finally the clean up.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dates
;
```

Final tip: date and datetime are kind of obsolete datetime types in SQL Server. Calculation with these is actually easier than the new datetime2 type allowing mathematical calculations.

datetime2 requires the Dateadd function use.
However datetime2 is easier to convert to current database interactions between different types of RDBMS. Also easier to work in standard ISO 8601 formats which makes transferring data between different parts of the world a whole lot easier.